# Can't read saved TensorFlow model (failed to seek to header entry)

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to read SavedModel with TensorFlow C++ API. The model was saved with TF Python code and my model directory has the following structure:

```
saved_model.pb
variables
├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
└── variables.index
```

I managed to read it successfully in Ubuntu with the following line of code:

```
tensorflow::LoadSavedModel(sessOpt, runOpt, modelDir, {tensorflow::kSavedModelTagServe}, &model);
```

However when I build the same code for Windows it fails to read the model. This is what TensorFlow outputs:

```
2017-07-25 16:16:15.112591: I C:\all\lib\serving\tensorflow\tensorflow\cc\saved_model\loader.cc:155]
Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2017-07-25 16:16:15.126391: W op_kernel.cc:1192]
Data loss: Unable to read file (C:/model/1/variables/variables.index).
Perhaps the file is corrupt or was produced by a newer version of TensorFlow with format changes (failed to seek to header entry): corrupted compressed block contents
2017-07-25 16:16:15.127325: W op_kernel.cc:1192]
Data loss: Unable to read file (C:/model/1/variables/variables.index).
Perhaps the file is corrupt or was produced by a newer version of TensorFlow with format changes (failed to seek to header entry): corrupted compressed block contents
...
Same lines over and over, 40 times in total
...
2017-07-25 16:16:15.162735: I C:\all\lib\serving\tensorflow\tensorflow\cc\saved_model\loader.cc:284] Loading SavedModel: fail. Took 80176 microseconds.
```

The version of TensorFlow is exactly the same, so there are no issues with that. The errors occur in the ctor `BundleReader::BundleReader` in the following line:

```
iter_->Seek(kHeaderEntryKey);
```

This is all part of the function that restores weights from the filesystem to the current session. TF basically runs `save/restore_all` operation to load the weights. Interestingly enough, it is done on a thread pool which on my machine has 12 threads. Due to that 12 threads simultaneously access `variables.index` file and I know that Windows does not like things like that.

I tried tuning session options for `LoadSavedModel` function:

```
sessionOpt.config.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
sessionOpt.config.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1);
sessionOpt.config.set_use_per_session_threads(1);
```

But unfortunately this does not seem to change anything.

Does anyone have any idea what else I can try? Should I file a bug report or maybe there's a problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the culprit. Turns out it's not related to multithreading issues.

The CMake build scripts provided in `tensorflow/contrib/cmake` do not support SNAPPY compression library, so the resulting application could not decompress my model. After I added SNAPPY library to `CMakeLists.txt` it started to work fine.

I'll most likely contribute the change soon so it can help the others having the same issue.